# Stopping the program after 1 second

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, motor, loop, sketch-size

I am a Beginner in Arduino Programming.
I am working on a project where I control A DC motor with IR sensor and arduino.

Until here it is fine. But I want the Motor to stop after one second even though the IR sensor detects the Obstacle

Here's My Program

Pin 2- IR Sensor
Pin 4,5,6- Motor

```
enter code here
//Included Libraries
#include <motor.h>

//MACROS are defined here
Motor Motor1(4, 5, 6);

void setup() {
    //put your setup code here, to run once:

    pinMode(2, INPUT);


}

void loop() {
    //put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


    if(digitalRead(2)) {
        Motor1.moveMotor(2.55*0);
    }
    else {
        Motor1.moveMotor(2.55*100);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help out in this Program. I Just want the Motor to stop after one second.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: First, edit your question, select all of your code, and tap the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: Also, you need to explain your goal more clearly. What should start your motor? The IR sensor? You say "I want the Motor to stop after one second as soon as the sensor detects the Obstacle." I don't understand what that means. You want it to run for at least one second no matter what, and after a second passes, have the IR sensor stop it if it detects and obstacle?

Comment: “_after one second_” alongside “_as soon as_” is a contradiction.

Comment: You show code that reads pin 2. Is that your IR sensor? What do the 2 different motor calls do? Does moveMotor(0) stop the motor, and moveMotor(255) cause the motor to move?

Comment: I am sorry, I dint make my point Clear. I edited the Question. Thanks

Comment: For doing timed things, learn how to use the `millis()` functions. Look at the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example and google for tutorials about that function. When you are understanding how these examples and tutorials work, you will be able to adapt that for your code.

Comment: The moveMotor(0) stops the motor and the moveMotor(2.25*100)  makes the motor run.

Comment: You improved a few things, but we still can't understand your goal. Please post a complete statement of how you want your sketch to behave. The phrase "I want the Motor to stop after one second as soon as the sensor detects the Obstacle" does not make sense. The "After one second" part is contradicted by the 
"as soon as the sensor detects an Obstacle" part.

Comment: Does `Motor1.moveMotor(2.55*100); delay(1000); Motor1.moveMotor(0);` work for you?

Comment: look at example sketches in the Arduino IDE ... look at the one named `StateChangeDetection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use read the time (`millis()`) when you start the motor and read it frequently while the motor is running to know when to stop it. You also need to keep track of the sensor, and don't start the motor again until after you've seen the sensor turn off (detect no obstacle). Here is an outline of the logic in psuedo-code; turn this into a detailed `loop()` function in C++:

```
if the motor is ON {
  if (millis() - motorStartMillis) > 1000 {
  stop the motor;
}
else if sensor is ON {
  if the sensor was OFF {
    start the motor;
    motorStartMillis = millis();
    sensorWasOn = true;
  }
}
else {      // sensor must be off
  sensorWasOn = false;
}
```